# Azure Data Factory invalid slices

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've come across this problem on multiple occasions so I've finally decided to ask about it... I have a pipeline with the following schedule:

```
    "start": "2016-10-04T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2099-12-31T06:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "xerox_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
```

On the Monitor and Manage page I have the following setting:
[image: date setting]

And yet for some reason, every slice before 10-17-2017 is considered invalid.

[image]

There is data in my database from before this time, so I know the slices must have ran at some point, but for some reason, I cannot click them from the monitor and manage page... Anyone else experience something like this? (Note: I am not using ADF v2.0)

Comment: Just to double check, it's probably not this, but something that catches me out no end, is making sure you click "apply" after selecting the dates.

Answer (score 2):

The monitor and management in ADFv1 can only retain a small amount of log data. It struggles with anything long term or complex. Especially if you have lots of datasets.

This isn't an answer, but its not you. Its just a "feature" of v1.

In ADFv2 you have the full power of logging to the Azure Monitor so this will be replace the bits from your screen shot.

Hope this helps.

Paul